# Kafka Sink Connector: Is there any way to apply value transformations only for messages that meet the condition?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch sink connector to transfer all messages to ES index.
There is a drop transformation for Kafka connectors, that tells connector to delete rows from ES if the body is null.

What if for delete action we send a message with not-null body? Is there any way to apply transformation with some condition/predicate, at the same time continue processing create/update messages without transformation? Like to apply drop value transformation only on rows that have deleted flag true in their bodies.

Answer (score 0):

The transforms don't "delete from ES", they only modify the Kafka record.

If you want to act only on specific records, that's what the Filter w/ Predicate transform is for, which you'd need to chain before a drop transformation since I don't think it's possible to invoke a delete ES event with a non-null record value

> at the same time continue processing create/update messages without transformation?

You'd need to run another connector that reverses the predicate condition of the other

Comment: I already mentioned about drop transformation with predicate, the problem here is that after applying filter transformation, it will not proceed to next steps with all other messages that do no meet the predicate condition. As a result connector will only process messages to be deleted. So the question here was about apply transformation on records to be deleted and skip that transformation for other rows, at the same time transfer all the messages(create+update+delete) to ES. Transformer do not delete the record, but it will be done by connector if the body will be null

Comment: If you need to process records with "different filters" differently, then you'd need to run different connectors. Or you can use Kafka Streams branch & map methods to split your input topic into two different topics, and consume those from one connector

Comment: If I'll split the messages to different topics, how can I guarantee the correct order of their processing for the next steps?

Comment: Records are individual documents as far as Elasticsearch is concerned; there would be no order there other than timestamps would would be unchanged in this model

Comment: the connector updates the record or delete them if find a new message with the same key - so they are not an individual for the current problem. There can be an issue of updating deleted doc and others..